# Why windows commands are not working in vscode-insiders' terminal (error: <3>init: (632) ERROR: UtilConnectUnix:466: connect failed 111)

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

- VSCode Version: 1.53.0-insider (x64)
- OS Version: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.21292.1010]
- WSL version: WSL 2
- distribution: Ubuntu-20.04

Steps to Reproduce:

1. (in wsl.exe)Type `code-insiders ~ && exit`
2. Press ctrl+j in the VSCode window
3. Type `explorer.exe .`

Result:
It shows me this error:
**<3>init: (632) ERROR: UtilConnectUnix:466: connect failed 111**

Question:
*How can I fix it and why it is happening ?*

Extensions on WSL:

- ms-vscode.cpptools
- eamodio.gitlens
- ms-toolsai.jupyter
- ms-python.vscode-pylance
- ms-python.python

Answer (score 2):

I think I had a similar issue here, you have to check the environment variables of you WSL2 session.

```
WSL_INTEROP=/run/WSL/197_interop
```

if this points to a not existing socket the connection fails.

cheers
Marco

Comment: I can confirm that this issue for the described symptoms. I can manually fix it by exporting the WSL_INTEROP variable to the newest available xxx_interop socket in the /run/WSL folder, e.g. `export WSL_INTEROP="/run/WSL/1491_interop"`. Any idea on how to automatically update the variable?

Answer (score -1):

close the terminal, If you facing this issue on vscode then close it and start again !